# GRASS GIS Error Flags

Tags: pyqgis, grass-gis, grass-7.0, grass.script

I am attempting to run a GRASS command from the terminal and eventually a bash script, in which it links rasters in a folder to the Mapset previously defined. I was able to successfully create the Mapset running a single line of code, however I receive the following error when I link the rasters:

`ERROR: Flag -e required also flag -c
Exiting...`

It is to my understanding that I can run this code without having to create a new Mapset for each raster (reason for omitting -c flag), and can also run this without initializing GRASS 7.0 text (reason for including the -e flag).

My line of code that prompted the error is as follows:
`grass70 /path/to/grassdata/urma_latest/PERMANENT/ -e --exec r.external input=urma_2018050900.tif output=urma1`

My goal is to run this for a series of rasters housed in the folder `/path/to/rasters/`

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the `--exec` option was added only since version 7.2. It seems you are running 7.0

Comment: Remove the `-e` flag. What happens? It should exit after an `--exec` call so you don't need the `-e` option.

Comment: Please consider to upgrade - even grass74 (grass70 is very old and we improved a lot the --exec job support).